# Jsoup fails to get outer HTML with nested tags

Tags: java, jsoup

after I connect to an Instagram page using Jsoup, I want to extract the whole outer html from a Tag. Somehow when I inspect the page and copy the outer html from the tag I get loads of lines, while I get only few using Jsoup (somehow the html of the nested tags gets ignored) Any help would be appreciated how to get the whole html!

**Code:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.instagram.com/myUsername").get();

Element link = doc.selectFirst("span");
String linkOuter = link.outerHtml();
System.out.println(linkOuter);
```

**Output**:

```
<span id="react-root">
  <svg width="50" height="50" viewbox="0 0 50 50" 
  style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-25px 0 0 
  -25px;fill:#c7c7c7">
    <path d="M25 1c-6.52 0-7.34.03-9.9.14-2.55.12-4.3.53-5.82..." />
</svg></span>
```

**Image of the structure:**
[image: Structure]

**EDIT:**
I wwant that the whole HTML of the span tag gets saved (I want the same result with HtmlUnit/Jsoup as when I right click on the tag click on edit html and then right click-> copy outer html!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Instagram is a Web app built with javascript framework react. That means, that final HTML is not returned from the server, but rather it's generated by javascript on client side on a browser after the initial loading of the page.

To see HTML generated by react you'd need to evaluate javascript code, which is returned from the server. `JSoup` is simple HTML parser and can't evaluate js, so you'd have to use another library, like for example HtmlUnit.

For example:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); //even if there is error in js continue
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(new URL("https://www.instagram.com/myUsername"));
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000); // important! wait when javascript finishes rendering

page.getElementById("react-root");
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I tried your code and it threw some Exceptions: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException **and** java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException **the first line causes the problem**

Comment: Just checked it with HtmlUnit 2.34.1 and it works fine, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.34.1. Please check if you're using right version.

Comment: So it works (to print the react one)  but the output isn't the one Expected --> if you manually copy the outer html of the span, insert it in e.g notepad ++ you will get an other result as with HtmlUnit... Any idea?

Comment: If you mean classes are different, they always would be different, because they're generated dynamically by styled-components module. If you mean, that markup is different, then maybe you'd have to interact with page somehow?

Comment: @Krzysztof Please fix your solution; waitForBackgroundJavaScript  has to be called AFTER getPage because this method is not an option.